# Can I get the return value inside 'ensure' in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
def some_method
  puts 'in method'
  return 'I am a return value'
ensure
  puts 'will print at the end'
  # Can I somehow get the return value of some_method here?
end
```

Is there some (possibly meta-programming) principle/way to get the return value of a method inside the "ensure" clause which is a part of the method definition (which we all know executes no matter what)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Assign a Variable

Just make your return value a variable. You can use the variable inside your ensure statement, but the return value for the method will be the last statement evaluated in the non-exceptional part of the method. For example:

```
def some_method
  puts 'in method'
  value = 'I am a return value'
ensure
  puts 'will print at the end'
  puts value
  true
end

some_method
#=> "I am a return value"
```

### Early Returns Work the Same

Note that the technique above works even if you return early, since the value passed to the *return* keyword is still the last non-exceptional expression evaluated. For example, the following method should never return false:

```
def return_true
  return value = true
  false
ensure
  puts value
  false
end

return_true
#=> true
```

Comment: What if you do return some_var = 'return value' ? I saw this works as well but not sure if there might be some hidden bugs lurking if this approach is used.

Comment: Just a small correction: since you are also printing the value with `puts value`, after the call to `return_true` you're missing `true` in stdout, not only the return value.

Comment: I wanted to wrap a method with begin/ensure so that I could log various return values. There were multiple `return true` and `return false` statements, so I changed them to `return (ret=true)`, etc., so that I could catch the return value with the `ret` variable in the ensure clause. My point is that using `return (ret=value)` can be a useful pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need this in `ensure`? If the main part of the method completed w/o exception the return value of that part will be returned from the method (unless you do `return` in `ensure`). If exception happens, the `return` in your main part is not calculated at all.

Of course you can always use the following (very ugly IMO) code. But please don't do that. A better idea is to leave only the resource-cleanup code in the ensure block.

```
def some_method
  finished = false
  begin
    puts 'in method'
    result = 'I am a return value'
    finished = true
  ensure
    puts 'will print at the end'
    # Do whatever is needed for cleanup
    if finished
      # Here result is defined, you can manipulate it if needed
      return result
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Here is a nice read on the subject: http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/rklemme/003-The_Universe_between_begin_and_end.html